# Network request failed with status 401 MarketingCloudSDK for ios

Tags: marketing-cloud, ios, mobilepush, sdk

I have created MarketingCloudSDK for IOS bindings in xamarin. I think that's working fine sdkstate looks good and deviceToken getting fine as well but still I am not able to see that contact in MobilePush.

```
    var config = new MarketingCloudSDKConfigBuilder()
        .Sfmc_setApplicationId(_applicationId)
        .Sfmc_setAccessToken(_accessToken)
        .Sfmc_setMid(_mID)
        .Sfmc_setMarketingCloudServerUrl(_mcUrl)
        .Sfmc_setAnalyticsEnabled(true)
        .Sfmc_setPiAnalyticsEnabled(true)
        .Sfmc_build();

        var isSuccessful = MarketingCloudSDK.SharedInstance().Sfmc_configureWithDictionary(config, out NSError error);

        if (isSuccessful)
        {
            MarketingCloudSDK.SharedInstance().Sfmc_setDebugLoggingEnabled(true);
            MarketingCloudSDK.SharedInstance().Sfmc_setContactKey("ABC123654");
            string contactKey = MarketingCloudSDK.SharedInstance().Sfmc_contactKey;
            string sdkstate = MarketingCloudSDK.SharedInstance().Sfmc_getSDKState;
            await base.InnerOpenChannel(ct);
        }
```

Here is my sdkState

```
"{\n  \"MarketingCloud Connection Details\" : 
{\n    \"Active AccessToken(Masked)\" : \"v*******************blpr\",
\n    \"Active AppId\" : \"Correct-value \"\n  },\n  \"Analytics Details\" : 
{\n    \"useLegacyPiIdentifier\" : false,\n    \"PiIdentifier\" : \"\",
\n    \"PIAnalyticsEnabled\" : true,\n    \"ETAnalyticsEnabled\" : true\n  },\n  \"Push Details\" : {\n    \"Developer has Push Enabled\" : \"Yes\",\n    \"Device Token\" : \"e300bb597d46f76697375566332211001jgrc476a2504fb22cf237e3c25268baa5b\",\n    \"User has Push Enabled\" : \"Yes\"\n  },\n  \"MarketingCloud SDK Features\" : {\n    \"Enabled by Configuration\" : \"ETAnalytics, PIAnalytics\"\n  },\n  \"Privacy Settings\" : {\n    \"Privacy Mode\" : \"SFMCPrivacyModeNotBlocked\"\n  },\n  \"Device Specific Details\" : {\n    \"OS Version\" : \"12.2\",\n    \"Hardware Description\" : \"iPhone10,5\",\n    \"Device Reported Timezone\" : \"-14400\",\n    \"Device Locale\" : \"en_CA\",\n    \"DeviceId\" : \"TFD554678-198A-42B2-ACC0-54654771\",\n    \"Daylight Savings Time Active\" : true,\n    \"Platform Name\" : \"iOS\"\n  }\n}"
```

I am not able to understand what went wrong
FYI:this sdkstate is after

```
public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(NSData deviceToken)
    {
        MarketingCloudSDK.SharedInstance().Sfmc_setDeviceToken(deviceToken);
        string sdkstate1 = MarketingCloudSDK.SharedInstance().Sfmc_getSDKState;
    }
```

Comment: is it possible that your access token or appId values have uppercase characters? We have a very recently identified issue in those cases, and using the ConfigBuilder method of SDK configuration, which will cause the 401 error you are seeing. Workaround: Use the JSON configuration technique. We will be releasing a fix for this soon, in our next SDK release.

Comment: @BrianM.Criscuolo this should be the answer rather than a comment.

Comment: That worked thanks.
My Xamarin bindings didn't add that json but I include in project manually and it seems working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved to answer:

Is it possible that your access token or appId values have uppercase characters? We have a very recently identified issue in those cases, and using the ConfigBuilder method of SDK configuration, which will cause the 401 error you are seeing. Workaround: Use the JSON configuration technique. We will be releasing a fix for this soon, in our next SDK release.